# What are the full names of all the outer planes?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, planes

I know there is the "Seven Mounting Heavens of Celestia" and the "Nine Hells of Baator" 
How many outer planes are there, and do they all have long names like this?

Comment: Probably you can find more information in "Manual of the Planes" by WoTC

Comment: This is arguably a setting-specific question. I say "arguably" because there are campaign settings that attempt to reconcile the apparently-different cosmologies of different campaign settings (generally by fingering some prime berks as clueless).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, they do all have long names. :) The seventeen outer planes are (listed on Manual of the Planes, p. 28) as follows. You can click each one for some information about it.

1. [Heroic Domain of Ysgard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ysgard)
2. [Ever-Changing Chaos of Limbo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limbo_%28Dungeons_&_Dragons%29)
3. [Windswept Depths of Pandemonium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandemonium_%28Dungeons_&_Dragons%29)
4. [Infinite Layers of the Abyss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abyss_%28Dungeons_&_Dragons%29)
5. [Tarterian Depths of Carceri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carceri)
6. [Gray Waste of Hades](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_Waste)
7. [Black Eternity of Gehenna](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gehenna_%28Dungeons_&_Dragons%29)
8. [Nine Hells of Baator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baator)
9. [Infernal Battlefield of Acheron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acheron_%28Dungeons_&_Dragons%29)
10. [Clockwork Nirvana of Mechanus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanus)
11. [Peaceable kingdoms of Arcadia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcadia_%28Dungeons_&_Dragons%29)
12. [Seven Mounting Heavens of Celestia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Celestia)
13. [Twin Paradises of Bytopia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytopia)
14. [Blessed Fields of Elysium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elysium_%28Dungeons_&_Dragons%29)
15. [Wilderness of the Beastlands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beastlands)
16. [Olympian Glades of Arborea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arborea_%28Dungeons_&_Dragons%29)
17. [Concordant Domain of the Outlands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlands_%28Dungeons_&_Dragons%29)

[The full table on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_Plane) has shorthand names for them and some base information as well.

Finally, the [entire cosmology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Dungeons_&_Dragons%29) talks about how those fit in with the other planes. [This beautiful map illustration of the Great Wheel](http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs11/i/2006/182/0/8/The_Planescape_Multiverse_by_zen79.jpg) may also be useful; it is based entirely on canon sources and quite accurate.

Comment: Quick note: the reason for the long names is that many (though not all) of these planes have gone through several different names over the course of the various editions and supplements. The "official" names in the 3e Manual of the Planes attempted to reconcile the most popular names from the various editions, either by straight-up combining multiple names (e.g. "The Nine Hells" of "Baator"), or at least giving a nod to several (e.g. "Plane of Concordant Opposition" -> "Concordant Domain of the Outlands").

Comment: Adding to what The Spooniest said, even in the game fiction, most planes have multiple names from different cultures, languages and dialects or just because people like to give multiple terms, titles and euphemisms to Very Big And Important Things; The natives of some campaign settings might not realise particular planes exist, or consider two distant parts of a single plane to be separate planes in their own right (perhaps to the annoyance of the natives).